# Jenkins Deploying to local maven repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy my artifacts to my local maven repository, but I keep running into issues. I have a `Post-build Action` defined to deploy my artifact to the following url: `file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/` but I keep getting the following failed build message:

```
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ouPerson/pom.xml to edu.oakland.ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0/ouPerson-0.2.0.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ouPerson/target/ouPerson-0.2.0.jar to edu.oakland.ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0/ouPerson-0.2.0.jar
channel stopped
Maven RedeployPublisher use remote  maven settings from : /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/_home_nick_bin_maven/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] Deployment in file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/ (id=ouPerson,uniqueVersion=true)
Deploying the main artifact ouPerson-0.2.0.jar
Uploading: file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0/ouPerson-0.2.0.jar
Uploading: file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0/ouPerson-0.2.0.pom
ERROR: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact edu.oakland.ouPerson:ouPerson:jar:0.2.0 from/to ouPerson (file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0
org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact edu.oakland.ouPerson:ouPerson:jar:0.2.0 from/to ouPerson (file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactRecord.deploy(MavenArtifactRecord.java:193)
    at hudson.maven.RedeployPublisher.perform(RedeployPublisher.java:176)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:756)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:669)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact edu.oakland.ouPerson:ouPerson:jar:0.2.0 from/to ouPerson (file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact edu.oakland.ouPerson:ouPerson:jar:0.2.0 from/to ouPerson (file:///home/nick/.m2/repository/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:335)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Specified destination directory cannot be created: /home/nick/.m2/repository/edu/oakland/ouPerson/ouPerson/0.2.0
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.createParentDirectories(AbstractWagon.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.fillOutputData(FileWagon.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getOutputStream(StreamWagon.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.put(StreamWagon.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:871)
    ... 16 more
[INFO] Deployment failed after 0.13 sec
Build step 'Deploy artifacts to Maven repository' changed build result to FAILURE
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: are you trying to physically copy the file to the .m2 folder?

Comment: That is the end result. I'd like jenkins to automate that process.

Comment: and can't you use `mvn deploy`?

Comment: I could use `mvn deploy` but I was trying to set it up for jenkins to automate the build, and then deploy it to my maven repository. I was, however, able to get it to work as expected See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the reason why it wasn't working. I originally installed maven via `apt-get`, however after having issues deploying, I decided to download the `war` file on [jenkins website](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and dropped the `war` into `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` and then I was able to deploy to local maven repository without any issues. Hope that helps those that are having similar issues!

Answer (score 0):

try 
`mvn install` 
This will install your artifact to your LOCAL maven repo. 
If you build your Jenkins job with maven, you have Top-Maven Target. Add this to your job with goals 
`clean install`
Don't forget add pom.xml in advance